# Firebase RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Can anyone help with this situation? I want to show history in a recycleview in a fragment from firebase database. But doesn't show. What went wrong i can not figure out. The app works fine but showing nothing in recyclerview.

My history class

```
public class History {

public String Date;
public String Amount;
public String Via;
public String Mobile_Number;

public History() {
}

public History(String date, String amount, String via, String mobile_Number)  
{
    Date = date;
    Amount = amount;
    Via = via;
    Mobile_Number = mobile_Number;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return Amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    Amount = amount;
}

public String getVia() {
    return Via;
}

public void setVia(String via) {
    Via = via;
}

public String getMobile_Number() {
    return Mobile_Number;
}

public void setMobile_Number(String mobile_Number) {
    Mobile_Number = mobile_Number;
}
}
```

I am using this viewholder class.

```
public class History {

public String Date;
public String Amount;
public String Via;
public String Mobile_Number;

public History() {
}

public History(String date, String amount, String via, String mobile_Number) 
{
    Date = date;
    Amount = amount;
    Via = via;
    Mobile_Number = mobile_Number;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return Amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    Amount = amount;
}

public String getVia() {
    return Via;
}

public void setVia(String via) {
    Via = via;
}

public String getMobile_Number() {
    return Mobile_Number;
}

public void setMobile_Number(String mobile_Number) {
    Mobile_Number = mobile_Number;
}
}
```

This fragment is used on pager.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, 
false);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
mMainView.findViewById(R.id.profile_recycler);


    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();


    mDatabase = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);



    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Users").child(uid).child("History").orderByKey();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<History> options = new 
FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<History>()
            .setQuery(query, History.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History,HistoryViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HistoryViewHolder holder, 
int position, @NonNull History model) {
            holder.setAmountText("100");
            holder.setDateText("dd-mm-yyyy");
            holder.setMobileText("model.getMobile_Number()");
            holder.setViaText("model.getVia()");
        }


        @Override
        public HistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_layout,parent,false);

            return new HistoryViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return mMainView;
}
```

History layout to populate every data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_mobile_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/history_date"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/history_date"
    android:text="Mobile Number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_via"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/history_mobile_number"
    android:layout_below="@id/history_mobile_number"
    android:text="Via"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/history_via"
    android:layout_below="@+id/history_via"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="Taka" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data you need to subscribe with

```
adapter.startListening();
```

and then unsubscribe with `adapter.stopListening();`

You need to start listening after you set your adapter. You can do it in `onStart()` method in the fragment and stop in `onStop()`. And before you do it add check for the adapter not being null or you may get a `nullpointerexeption`. This firebase adapter can be tricky. Once I tried to use it and ended up rewriting the whole thing with the regular RecyclerViewAdapter class.

Also, I see you're using the `""` around the method calls. You are creating a string from this text and it won't be called as expected. Remove the `""`

```
@Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HistoryViewHolder holder, 
int position, @NonNull History model) {
            holder.setAmountText("100");
            holder.setDateText("dd-mm-yyyy");
            holder.setMobileText(model.getMobile_Number());
            holder.setViaText(model.getVia());
        }
```

Comment: " " was actually used to check whether the problem is with inflation or retrieving data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask answer directly in Stackoverflow, as a software developer, you should learn to debug, if you can't debug, you can post the exception message alongside with the code, not just code.

Suggestion for you:

1. Go through the [sample app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/firestore) from Firebase, it's well developed.

Possible problem:

1. Your database key has a different name from your History class. Solution for this will be rename all objects name in either your database/code.  For e.g.:

   ```
   public String Date;
   ```

to

```
public String date; 
//make sure your database date has the same naming convention(spelling, capitalisation etc).
```

That's how I solved my problem last time.